# Stream multiple images from OpenCV at the same time

Tags: python, performance, opencv, user-interface, pyqt5

I am working on a GUI in pyqt and I want to display both the original and processed images coming from OpenCV. My have an attempt using two pyslots, but they show the same image. I am not sure how to do this without having the same code for each image which seems inefficient.

```
from pypylon import pylon
#from pypylon_opencv_viewer import BaslerOpenCVViewer

import cv2
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import  QWidget, QLabel, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, Qt, pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot
from PyQt5.QtGui import QImage, QPixmap
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp2d


class Thread(QThread):
    
    #changePixmap = pyqtSignal(QImage)
    changePixmap_raw = pyqtSignal(QImage)
    changePixmap_th = pyqtSignal(QImage)
    
    def run(self):
        
        def process_image(img):

            *SNIP*

            
            return result
            
        serial_number = '23437639'
        info = None 

        for i in pylon.TlFactory.GetInstance().EnumerateDevices():
            if i.GetSerialNumber() == serial_number:
                info = i 
                break  
        else:
            print('Camera with {} serial number not found '.format(serial_number))

        if info is not None:
            camera = pylon.InstantCamera(pylon.TlFactory.GetInstance().CreateDevice(info))
            camera.Open()
        

        # Grabing Continusely (video) with minimal delay
        camera.StartGrabbing(pylon.GrabStrategy_LatestImageOnly)
        converter = pylon.ImageFormatConverter()

        # converting to opencv bgr format
        converter.OutputPixelFormat = pylon.PixelType_BGR8packed
        converter.OutputBitAlignment = pylon.OutputBitAlignment_MsbAligned

        while camera.IsGrabbing():
            grabResult = camera.RetrieveResult(5000, pylon.TimeoutHandling_ThrowException)

            if grabResult.GrabSucceeded():
                img = converter.Convert(grabResult)
                img = img.GetArray()
                img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
                h, w = img.shape
                result_img = process_image(img)
                bytesPerLine = w
                original_QT = QImage(img.data, w, h, bytesPerLine, QImage.Format_Grayscale8)
                threshold_QT = QImage(result_img.data, w, h, bytesPerLine, QImage.Format_Grayscale8)
                p1 =  original_QT.scaled(640, 480, Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
                p2 = threshold_QT.scaled(640, 480, Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
                self.changePixmap_raw.emit(p1)
                self.changePixmap_th.emit(p2)


class App(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        [...]
        self.initUI()

    @pyqtSlot(QImage)
    def setImage_raw(self, image):
        self.label_raw.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(image))


    @pyqtSlot(QImage)
    def setImage_th(self, image):
        self.label_th.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(image))


    def initUI(self):
        #self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        #self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)
        self.resize(1800, 1200)
        # create a label
        self.label_raw = QLabel(self)
        self.label_raw.move(280, 120)
        self.label_raw.resize(640, 480)
        self.label_th = QLabel(self)
        self.label_th.move(1000,120)
        self.label_th.resize(640,480)
        th = Thread(self)
        th.changePixmap_raw.connect(self.setImage_raw)
        th.changePixmap_th.connect(self.setImage_th)
        th.start()
        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I am hoping to add two more views and I would hate to add 2 more emitters etc... to implement that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to store a copy of the original image `orig_img = img.copy()`

Comment: @Christoffer does that helpe avoid having a separate emitter for each stream I want to show?